# What is database backed Cache and how does it work?

Tags: asp.net

What is database backed Cache and how does it work ? Something similar in line of when the app server goes down and database is backed by cache there is no time wasted to repopulate an in memory cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A database backed cache is a method of storing data that is costly (in resources or time) to generate or derive.  You could see them implemented for such things as:

- improving web server performance by caching dynamic pages in a db as static html so additional hits to the page do not incur the overhead of regenerating the page.  Yes, this might be counter-intuitive as often database access is the bottleneck, though in some cases it is not.
- Improving query time against a slow (or offsite) directory server or database.

If I understand your example correctly, I believe you might have it backwards.  The database is *backing* some other primary location.  For example, in an app server farm, if a security token is stored in a db backed cache and the app server you are currently interacting with goes down you could be routed to a different service instance. The token cache check it's in-memory cache which won't contain the token, so it will be retrieved from the database, deserialized and added to the (new) local cache.  The benefits are minimized network transport and improved resilience to failures.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the input I wanted to know  if there are any techniques from which I can save my cache data in the database just before it is about to fail or when it Has already failed.

Comment: @nik - http://stackoverflow.com/q/1635320/573083 has some additional information and discussion.

Comment: thank's but it look's like they are discussing distributed caching libraries , I was looking for a fail over solution for a caching.